# in ckeditor plugin, why isn't my getConfig returned array affecting editor?

Tags: wysiwyg, plugins

I'm including the [wordcount](http://ckeditor.com/addon/wordcount) plugin to CKEditor in D8. I'm including some configuration (`maxWordCount`) through the configurable interface. The issue I'm having is that no matter what I return from `getConfig` there's no affect on the editor.

```
class WordCount extends CKEditorPluginBase implements CKEditorPluginContextualInterface {

  public function isEnabled(Editor $editor) {
    return TRUE;
  }

  public function isInternal() {
    return FALSE;
  }

  public function getFile() {
  return drupal_get_path('module', 'ckeditor_maxlength') . '/wordcount/plugin.js';
  }


  public function getConfig(Editor $editor) {
  // just return a hardcoded maxWordCount.
    return [
      'maxWordCount' => 10,
    ];
  }

  public function getButtons() {
  // No buttons needed.
  }
}
```

To be clear the counter works as expected, but I don't seem to be able to override the default configuration.

Inside the core ckeditor module the `getConfig` function has this notation:

```
* @return array
*   A keyed array, whose keys will end up as keys under CKEDITOR.config.
```

When I inspect `CKEditor.config` in the console I don't see the configurations, and infact, the `wordcount` plugin is buried in `CKEditor.plugins.externals`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was just formatting the array improperly. In order to return the configuration to my `wordcount` plugin I did this:

```
 return ['wordcount' => ['maxWordCount' => '10']];
```